# How is the child access another child's protected member via member method

Tags: c++, inheritance, public

How is this compiled? variable **d** inside protected. How child class method **works** able to modify another instance of child class protected member variable? Can the child access another child's protected member via member method

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << d;
    }
protected:
    int d = 2;
};

class Child : public Parent
{

public:
    void works(Child* some_other_child)
    {
        some_other_child->d = 3;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Parent *p = new Parent();
    Child *c = new Child();
    Child *co = new Child();
    c->works(co);
    co->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`protected` and `private` keywords limit which *classes* can access a member-variable, not which *objects* can access it.

As such, code in the `Child::works()` method is able to access the protected `Parent::d` member-variable of any `Child` object, because `Child` is a subclass of `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Child` class is inherited from the `Parent` class, the `Child` class inherits the `int d` member variable. When the constructor of `Child` class is called, it creates the `int d` member variable as a member of `Child` class. The `int d` in `Child` is again a `protected` member variable.

Then if you call a method of `Child` class it naturally has access to all members of class it is owned by. So as the `works` method is owned by `Child` class, it has access to `int d` member variable and it is allowed to change it (if you don't make it a const method, such as `void works(Child* some_other_child) const`, it would mean, that the method is not allowed to change any member variables of its class).

When you pass a pointer (or a reference) to another object of `Child`, as it is called from `Child`'s method it can change the members too, because it has access to `Child`'s member variables.